# iOS in app purchase - No longer getting sandbox prompt after rejection

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

My recent version of app with in app purchase got rejected.  (Everything was working fine before the rejection.) Now when using Xcode for recompiling and installing  the app onto the device (iPad mini), I'm no longer getting the sandbox sign-in prompt.  I made sure I've logged out of the App Store before installing the app using Xcode.

I realize there are a lot of similar problems posted.  I've looked at all the answers and tried them all without success.  Specifically I tried/wondered about:

1) The products were marked rejected in iTunesConnect, and I edited the description and saved and they now have status 'waiting for review'.
  - Just to be sure, I also tried creating a new product, that didn't make the prompt come up still.

2) I did notice that in the Xcode, using the same provisioning profile, now under capabilities/in-app-purchase it's asking me to fix.  But I've gotten that before once and fixed without causing problems.  In any case I've turned it on and now it reflects that.

3) I'm using the cc.fovea.cordova.purchase plugin instead of working directly with StoreKit, but that shouldn't matter as it worked in previous submissions, although this is the first time I submitted in app purchases.

4) Is it possible to get locked out of in app purchase sandbox because I accidentally said no to sandbox too many times? I read that could happen with Game Center, but haven't read that happening with in-app-purchase sandbox.

5) Occasionally I can get the products back from the App Store, even though not able to log in.   You can see that loaded=false.

```
Object
alias: "Bronze"
canPurchase: false
currency: null
description: null
id: "<app name>.plan1d"
loaded: false
owned: false
price: null
state: "registered"
title: null
transaction: null
type: "paid subscription"
```